# How does Chrome knows when Flash crashed?

Tags: c++, flash, google-chrome

unfortunately many times the Flash plugin at Google's Chrome crashes. But fortunately, they just present a message box and a [sad face](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3241/2845094325_e667913ba9_o.gif).

My question is, how do they do it? my first thought is that they use [structured exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(VS.85).aspx) but then again, how they know its Flash that crashed?

thanks for any ideas!
Lior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they run it in a separate process.  when the child process terminates, the parent is notified by the operating system.  the parent can then query the system about the nature of the termination.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome runs plugins in an entirely separate process from the rest of the page.

If the process ever crashes or locks up, then the plugin must be dead.